# removing /index.html in RTF in DXA 1.7 .NET

Tags: dxa, dynamic-linking, dxa-1.7, .net

I have a request to strip all ./index.html in DXA 1.7 .NET rich text field for component links. Is there an option to do this easily?

Should I extend RichText class?

Should I extend content service link resolving?

What is the best practice and how to do it?

Comment: Please elaborate what you want to strip exactly. Do you mean remove `/index.html ` suffixes from resolved links?

Comment: no, dxa already removes index.html. i want to additionally remove /. I did it by extending HTML helpers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So for those that are interested in a solution, I did this by creating my own DxaRichText HTML helper extension and doing the change there.
Code looks something like this

```
 public static MvcHtmlString MyDxaRichText(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, RichText richText)
    {
        if (richText == null)
        {
            return MvcHtmlString.Empty;
        }

        StringBuilder htmlBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (IRichTextFragment richTextFragment in richText.Fragments)
        {
            EntityModel entityModel = richTextFragment as EntityModel;
            string htmlFragment = (entityModel == null) ? richTextFragment.ToHtml() : htmlHelper.DxaEntity(entityModel).ToString();
```

.....

and so on. You get the point.